# Android Studio - Can I create a custom device profile?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently experimenting with some Android app building, and using a physical Lenovo device to test with. Android Studio comes with a pretty decent range of device layouts that look like so:

[image]

Unfortunately, none of the devices listed fit the specification of my device, in terms of size/ratio etc, and it's forcing design elements to appear in weird places on my screen (unsurprisingly). My question is basically: can I create a custom layout for my device?

I understand that I can create a virtual device with a specified layout, and that's pretty much my plan B, but it seems like there would be a simple function to create your own layouts, there's even a 'custom' selection in the drop-down.

I've searched for similar queries to this and have come up short, which might mean that this is so simple that no one's had to ask before. Either way, any help is appreciated.